# Can shiny app assign values to objects in R global environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering if it's possible for a shiny app that's not run on the web (i.e. it's only run by a user launching it from their R session) to assign values to objects in the user's global environment. For example, suppose that as part of the app a data.frame is generated and, instead of using a download button to save the data.frame to a file, is it possible to assign it to an object in the user's R session so that when they close the app the data.frame is available to them?

Answer (score 0):

What about automatically save the entire environment (using "save" function) to a temporary file? Then, you can just load it (using "load" function) and your data frame will be in the environment. All this process can be easily automated, without needing to use any save button.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I'll think about that. My original thought was to have it set up so that there was a "save to file" button (which opens the download dialogue) and an "export to R" button which assigns the content to an object in the users R environment.